# How do I transform my <img> tag from javascript to actual picture in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, mysql

I'm making a chat in html with php and I want my users profile pictures next to their message. I fetch the text, name and img tag of the profile picture from a sql table but when I create a div with the text, the url is still a tag with letters and not the picture as intended. The first function (load) fetches the information and sends it to the second function (createDiv) that creates a div and sends it to an already existing div on the main html page.

```
function load(name){ 
    getText("ajax.php");    
    async function getText(file) {    
        let myObject    = await fetch(file);     
        let myText        = await myObject.text(); 
        const myArray = myText.split("::");
        for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length -1; i++) {
            createDiv(myArray[i], myArray[i+1], myArray[i+2], name);
            i++;
            i++;
        }
    }
}


function createDiv(divText, divName, divPicture, name){
    let child = document.createElement("div");      
    let content = document.createTextNode(divPicture + divName  + ": " + divText);  

    child.appendChild(content);         
                
    document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(child);
}
```

I've tried adding the following code on the end of my createDiv function to send the picture to another div but still no picture, it just creates another white box.

```
var img = new Image(); 
img.src =  divPicture; 
img.className = "pic"; 
document.getElementById(tmp).appendChild(img);
```

This is what writes out on the message box:

```
<img src= 'uploads/defaultpp.png' alt='Profile Picture' width='500' height='600'>username: text
```

Any ideas of how I send it so it actually becomes a picture from the img tag and not just the tag with letters?

Comment: Your source may not be full path to find the image.  I would check the path from the webpage you are on to the folder where the images are stored.

Comment: Good code indentation and layout ___is for life, not just for Christmas___ and would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch the data from database, it still html. So when you are appending it, **don't use [createTextNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode)** for appending. The **createTextNode will escape the html**. And it will not render on the browser. Instead use **innerHTML** to insert the html.

Here is the Update code of **createDiv() function**:-

```
function createDiv(divText, divName, divPicture, name){
    let child = document.createElement("div");
    child.innerHTML = divPicture + divName  + ": " + divText;      
    document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(child);
}
```

Hope it will be helpful.